# Es buena práctica crear codigo html con Js?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la duda de hasta qué punto es bueno crear html con js, quiero saber cuales son los pro y los contra de esta práctica... Me surgió la duda porque estoy queriendo hacer una galeria que se muestre cuando le de click a un botón, puedo hacerlo de varias formas pero quiero saber cual es la más apropiada.

1.Puedo crear otro documento html que cuando le de click al botón me redirija a este index.

2.Puedo crear la galeria en el mismo html donde este el botón y jugar con display:none/block para mostrarlo y ocultarlo

3.Puedo crear codigo html desde un archivo js al capturar el evento click del botón que quiero usar.

Mi idea es que se renderice rápido y que no le consuma muchos datos al cliente...

Comment: Lo mas apropiado ¿para quién? ¿para el desarrollador, el usuario, o quien mantiene la aplicación? ¿para qué? ¿para estabilidad, desempeño, mantenibilidad, experiencia de usuario, etc? ¿Cuánto es "muchos datos"? El primer consejo es distinguir entre lo estático y lo dinámico.

Comment: También debes considerar si quieres que ese contenido sea indexable por google o no (google no indexa muy bien el contenido dinámico via javascript) [ask] - [tour]

Comment: Depende de cómo y para qué.

Comment: Pues, los front end frameworks basados en Javascript hacen eso, no? Crean un virtual DOM usando js?